# Searching CSV-File for 2 key words using Terminal and create a new csv file

Tags: csv, terminal, grep, keyword

I have a couple of CSV-Files which are quite large (up to 130GB). Since I do not need data from 2017 and back I want to grep the data from 2018 upwards (Data only until June 2019) and create a new csv file to make it smaller.

I tried this:

```
grep "2018-" file.csv | grep "2019-" > file_1819.csv
```

currently it only looks for files that have both timestamps in one row (So basically comment made 2018-04-01 expires 2019-04-01). I need this as well but what I also need:

Is a row only has made 2018-05-01 and no expire date. Currently it does not include this in the new csv file.

Sample would be:

> Input-File

```
4108,48.74,"2017-09-16 16:15:04"
4249,8.1,"2017-09-16 16:15:04"
4197,3.81,"2017-09-16 17:20:00"
4139,26.81,"2018-09-16 16:15:04"
4218,24.83,"2018-09-16 17:20:00"
4260,79.72,"2018-09-16 16:15:04"
4270,450.12,"2019-09-16 17:20:00"
4242,30.38,"2019-09-16 16:15:04"
4193,1.42,"2019-09-16 16:15:04"
4134,3.77,"2019-09-16 16:15:04
```

> Outputfile:

```
    4139,26.81,"2018-09-16 16:15:04"
    4218,24.83,"2018-09-16 17:20:00"
    4260,79.72,"2018-09-16 16:15:04"
    4270,450.12,"2019-09-16 17:20:00"
    4242,30.38,"2019-09-16 16:15:04"
    4193,1.42,"2019-09-16 16:15:04"
    4134,3.77,"2019-09-16 16:15:04
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sample would be:

Id: 1 Date: 2017
Id: 2 Date: 2018
Id: 3 Date: 2019
Id: 4 Date: 2018/2019
Id: 5 Date: 2016

Outputfile:
Id: 2 Date: 2018
Id: 3 Date: 2019
Id: 4 Date: 2018/2019

Comment: Does your input file is "Id: 1 Date: 2017-X Id: 2 Date: 2018-X Id: 3 Date: 2019-X Id: 4 Date: 2018/2019-X Id: 5 Date: 2016-X", without any carriage return?

Comment: thanks for the help. I updated the file so you exactly see what I meant. Hope this example makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Should I give another example? or is it clear what I try to do/get?